# Better approach to create a unique list of keys in inner dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Better approach to create a unique list of keys in inner dictionary in Python

I have dictionary as follows :

```
users3 = {"David": {"Imagine Dragons": 3, "Daft Punk": 5, "Lorde": 4, "Fall Out Boy": 1},
          "Matt": {"Imagine Dragons": 3, "Daft Punk": 4, "Lorde": 4, "Fall Out Boy": 1},
          "Ben": {"Kacey Musgraves": 4, "Imagine Dragons": 3, "Lorde": 3, "Fall Out Boy": 1},
          "Chris": {"Kacey Musgraves": 4, "Imagine Dragons": 4, "Daft Punk": 4, "Lorde": 3, "Fall Out Boy": 1},
          "Tori": {"Kacey Musgraves": 5, "Imagine Dragons": 4,"Daft Punk": 5, "Fall Out Boy": 3}}
```

(taken from : http://guidetodatamining.com/)

My objective is to create matrix of "items based similarity" between keys in inner dictionary. 
I believe i have to generate list of unique keys in inner dictionary first, i've done it using the following script :

```
def masterOfTitle(users3):
    master_title = []
    for (users, ratings) in users3.items():
        for key in ratings.keys():
            if key not in master_title:
                master_title.append(key)
    return master_title
```

and finally, the result as expected :

```
>>> titles = masterOfTitle(users3)
>>> titles
['Daft Punk', 'Kacey Musgraves', 'Lorde', 'Fall Out Boy', 'Imagine Dragons']
>>>
```

CMIIW, at least for me (as a newbie) Python's programming logic/flow is little bit differ from any other i've learnt (c, delphi/pascal, vb) 
Is there a better approach using comprehension expression?.
Kindly need your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) to collect the unique keys:

```
def masterOfTitle(users3):
    titles = set()
    for nested in users3.itervalues():
        titles.update(nested)
    return titles
```

If you really want to, you can use a set comprehension for that too:

```
def masterOfTitle(users3):
    return {title for nested in users3.itervalues() for title in nested}
```

The book you link to appears to be using Python 2 for the examples (they used `codecs.open()` for unicode encoding / decoding), so I used `dict.itervalues()` iterate over the values in the most efficient manner possible.

Demo:

```
>>> masterOfTitle(users3)
set(['Daft Punk', 'Fall Out Boy', 'Lorde', 'Kacey Musgraves', 'Imagine Dragons'])
```